# What is the ball associated with a certain metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I do not understand what the ball associated with a certain metric is. How do you obtain the radius and centre of such ball? Should you just take an arbitrary point?

Comment: In what context have you encountered "**the** ball associated with a certain metric" as if there were just one such ball?

Comment: Both the center and the radius have to be given to specify a ball. Typically metric spaces have a very large number of distinct balls (for example, any pair of real numbers $(x,r)$ with $r>0$ specifies a ball in the real numbers).

Comment: Then for each arbitrary point there is a ball with r>0?

Comment: For every metric space $X$ with metric denoted $d$, and for every point $p \in X$, and for every real number $r > 0$, the ball in $X$ with center $p$ and radius $r$ is defined to be the set $\{y \in X \mid d(x,y) < r\}$.

Comment: We use the term *ball* generically with metric $d$ to mean the set "centered" at  $x$ having radius $r$ that @LeeMosher describes.  The actual shape could be quite different from "round", use of the word *ball* notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a metric $d$ on a set $S$ and for $p\in S$ and for $r\in \Bbb R$ the $open$ ball $B_d(p,r)$ is defined as $$B_d(p,r)=\{q\in S: d(q,p)<r\}.$$ Non-positive values of $r$ are rarely mentioned because $B_d(p,r)=\emptyset$ when $r\leq 0.$

When only one metric $d$ is under discussion, $B_d(p,r)$ is often written as  $B(p,r).$

Some people write $B_r(p)$ instead, which I think is harder to read, and can become awkward when $r$ is defined by a formula instead of a single letter.

$p$ is called a center of $B_d(p,r)$ and $r$ is called a radius of $B_d(p,r).$ (Note: Not necessarily "the" center nor "the" radius. See below.)

In some metric spaces (...e.g. $S=\Bbb R$ with $d(p,q)=|p-q|...),$ if $r,r'>0$ and $B(p,r)=B(p',r')$ then $p=p'$ and $r=r'.$  But in general this may not happen.

The simplest example is to let $S$ have more than one member, and let $d(p,p')=1$ when $p,p'$ are unequal members of $S$. (This is called the discrete metric on $S.$)   Then for any $p,p'\in S$ we have $B_d(p,2)=B_d(p',3)=S. $ And for any $r,r'\in (0,1]$ and any $p\in S$ we have $B_d(p,r)=B_d(p,r')=\{p\}.$

Comment: @RossMillikan.  I said the ball is empty for r<0. The def'n makes sense for r<0. It's just  that the case r<0 is not very interesting